# Set a null value in a masked box

Tags: mysql, sql-server, vb.net, date

This command works in a formload. I want to update my database with spsbday having a value of 0000-00-00 to a null value. Can anyone reconstruct my code? It's currently giving me a headache.

```
If conn.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
    conn.Open()
End If
Dim query As String
query = "update member set spsbday = null where spsbday = 0000-00-00"
sqlcom = New MySqlCommand(query, conn)
conn.Close()
```

Comment: `update member set spsbday = null where spsbday = '0000-00-00'`

Comment: Please choose the correct tag. MySql or Sql Server?

Comment: In addition to @lad2025 comment which is correct if `spsbday` datatype is Date,  you missed `sqlcom.ExecuteNonQuery` after `sqlcom = New MySqlCommand(query, conn)` Otherwise data will not be updated.